# Content security policy + Form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, content-security-policy

I'm posting this question without code as I don't have access to it atm but the web page concerned can be view here:

http://sensing-precision.com/equipment-hire/

I have content in link-able DIVs which are wrapped in a DIV with

```
display:none
```

set so that the content isn't visible. I'm using jQuery script to enable loading of the hidden content into the target DIV:

```
ITarget
```

My problem is the enquiry form. I'm using a plugin called Ninja Forms on Wordpress and the form works fine. I've tested it prior to embedding it on this page. However, for some reason, placing it in this "hidden" content section and loading it via jQuery when clicking on the link "Enquiry Form" is causing an error. Click on the submit button to see what I mean.

Now I recently set the Content Security Policies via the .htaccess file and I get the feeling I'm not setting something that I need to be setting.

I've included the

```
'self' 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'
```

in the Script-src among the specific external sites required for the website. But I can't fathom why if I embed this form simply on a page on its own, or even on the same page outside the hidden content DIV, it works fine. But hidding the form and loading it to the Target DIV causes a javascript error??

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot target children of elements initialized with `display:none`. You could try setting `visibility:hidden` instead, or have it load normally and use javascript to hide it after, ie.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $(".yourdiv").hide();
)};
```

I'm not sure that necessarily solves your problem though as it looks like it's failing server side. Could you post a more complete example in a fiddle?

Comment: The `.hide()` actually improved the performance of the page I reckon but alas your suspicisons were correct, it did not solve the problem. I have tried the `visibility: hidden` route as well but no dice.

Comment: I also was wrong about it being a content security policy issue, I removed the entire CSP and got the same error....